# Sub-Query in Mysql: Join on two table with string concatenation

Tags: mysql

I have question regarding sub query in MySQL. Problem is:-

There is two table

1. userfirst
2. userlast

describe userfirst

```
id firstname
1  Anurag
2  Abhishek
3  Prashant
```

describe userlast

```
src lastname
F/1 Jain
F/2 Singh
F/3 Sharma
```

Now I want output like:-

```
id firstname lastname
1  Anurag    Jain
2  Abhishek  Singh
3  Prashant  Sharma
```

I want to write only one query like:-

```
select 
  f.id,
  f.firstname, 
  (select l.lastname from userlast l where l.src = 'F/'+f.id) as name 
from userfirst f
```

Is above query is possible, if yes/no Please tell the correct solution ?

Thanks

Comment: In second table why are you storing `F/id` what is the reason behind it if `F` is some type then you can add other column and store that type in this

Comment: Actually original table structure is different , there are three or four type like 'node/1' 'job/1' etc. and I have no access to change in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `JOIN` its much more efficient :

```
SELECT
    f.id,
    f.firstname,
    l.lastname
FROM
    userfirst f
LEFT JOIN userlast l
    ON l.src = CONCAT('F/',f.id)
```

You can see the result [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d859/4) , fiddle provided by `Meherzad`

Answer (score 1):

In mysql there are many functions for string manipulation including concat
you can use like

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT('My', 'S', 'QL');
        -> 'MySQL'
```

I guess you can use
select f.id,f.firstname, (select l.lastname from userlast l where l.src = concat('F/',f.id) as name from userfirst f

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    f.id,
    f.firstname,
    l.lastname
FROM
    userfirst f
INNER JOIN userlast l
    ON l.src = CONCAT('F/',f.id)
```